# Can Scala pattern match to anonymous class?

Tags: scala

Suppose we have anonymous class generator:

```scala
// test class...
def fixture = new {
  val stubA = 42
  val stubB = 24
}
```

Then I'd like to pattern match and extract fields like this:

```scala
val { stubA } = fixture
```

Unfortunately, Scala don't have this feature (TypeScript does) afaik.

Of course, using case class enables this:

```scala
case class Fixture(stubA: Int, stubB: Int)
def fixture = Fixture(42, 24)

val Fixture(stubA, _)= fixture
```

Obviously, this is too complex; we need just only named value.

Can I pattern match from anonymous class in simpler way?

Comment: I’m not sure, but maybe a tuple would suit?

Answer (score 3):

No, and further, that syntax doesn't do what you think it does. Anonymous classes are intended to override behaviors of some well-defined interface. So, for instance, we could make an anonymous class which implements [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and has custom `run()` behavior. But they can't really meaningfully add fields or methods to the parent that weren't there to begin with.

```
def fixture = new {
  val stubA = 42
  val stubB = 24
}
```

The type of `fixture` is `Object`. That's because you made an anonymous subclass of `Object`. You can call `Object` things on `fixture`, like `toString()` or `equals(...)`. But you can't write `fixture.stubA`, because `stubA` doesn't exist on `Object`.

So not only can you not pattern match against these custom anonymous-only fields and methods, but you can't even call them using conventional syntax. You can *only* access them using Java Reflection.<sup>[1]</sup>

The bottom line is: If you're trying to write Javascript (or Typescript) in Scala, you're going to be in for a rough time. The two languages have very different approaches to problem solving, and you've just found a great example of this. Typescript code is absolutely riddled with object literals that satisfy some structural interface, but anonymous class instances are *uncommon* in Scala. That's why Scala gives us `case class`es and synthetic `apply` constructors and all the other convenient ways to shorten class declarations. We're supposed to declare classes liberally.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> And even doing it with Java Reflection is rife with landmines. You have to know how Scala compiles instance variables. Java Reflection sees 0-argument methods `int stubA()` and `int stubB()`. The fields themselves are private, so they can be detected by `getDeclaredFields()` but not `getFields()`. Bottom line: It's a mess.

Answer (score 2):

If you modified your code, to this:

```
def fixture: Any { val stubA: Int; val stubB: Int } = new {
  val stubA = 42
  val stubB = 24
}
```

then you would create a refined type. Actually, Scala compiler always create refined type when you do anything like `new Type { /* new definitions */ }` but depending on version it might upcast it to the type you refine unless you tell it explicitly to preserve the refinement.

Could you make a pattern match with that?

To be able to pattern match you have to have an extractor (a value with `unapply` method defined), it cannot be just `{}`. So you could write for instance:

```
type Helper = Any { val stubA: Int; val stubB: Int } 
object Helper {
  def unapply(helper: Helper): Some[(Int, Int)] =
    Some((helper.stubA, helper.stubB))
}

def fixture: Helper = new {
  val stubA = 42
  val stubB = 24
}

val Helper(stubA, stubB) = fixture
```

However, this may look like too much work when compared to using a single-use `case class`.

If this "anonymous class generator" would also generate some alias AND some extractor, that issue would be addressed (although it would still be non-idiomatic).

Finally, one could use some whitebox macros/transparent inline to generate this `unapply` method implementation... but while it would work it would not cooperate with IDEs very much.

So, I would still go with either single-usage case class or refined type without pattern match/destructuring (or a tuple as the commenter suggested). Because it cooperates with existing tooling.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you find "complex" about your latter snippet. That you have to name your class? Naming things hardly qualifies as "complexity" in my book, I'd say, it's rather mundane ...

Anyhow, it is not very clear from your question what it is exactly you are trying to achieve, but what you have written is sorta reminiscent of a pattern people sometimes use to create unit tests in scala:

```
class FooBarSpec extends FunSpec with MockitoSugar { 

   trait Fixture { 

      val fooMock = mock[Foo]
      val barMock = mock[Bar]

      when(fooMock.doFoo()).thenReturn("foo")
      when(barMock.doBar()).thenReturn("bar")

      val testMe = new FooBar(fooMock, barMock)
  }

  describe("FooBar") { 
    it ("does stuff") (new Fixture { 
    
     
     testMe.doStuff() mustBe "foobar"

     verify(fooMock).doFoo() 
     verify(barMock).doBar()
   })
 }
}
```

The idea is the you create your `Fixture` trait where you define your stubs and common behaviors for all of your tests. And then each test happens in the body of a constructor of an anonymous subclass of  that fixture. That way inside your test you have access to all the common definitions, and can override them as needed for the particular test case.